# Downloadable file path in windows 8 Metro apps?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Hi am trying to download a file in metro app,am able to download a file but it is storing in Pictures Library or Documents Library folders.Those folders am specifying in the following line in my project.
Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.***documentsLibrary***.createFileAsync();

But, instead of specifying above paths ,I want to download a file and it has to store in Downloads-Folder in my PC.If I set file-url dynamically,it is saying that file-url is only readable we cant edit.so how can I download a file into downloads folder?can anyone give me advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the Downloads folder directly as - contrary to the Documents library - there's no special capability for this folder.

You'll have to use a FileOpenPicker to let the user select a folder where they want to have their downloads stored. Then you can store the access token and use it for subsequent files.
For more information on access tokens and the FileOpenPicker, see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655411.aspx

Depending on your use case you may want to download the files into your applications localstorage folder and let the user copy or open them individually from within your app.